# Git stay on same commit but revert files

Tags: git

I want to get reset files to previous commit but staying on the current commit. So if I do:

```
git init
touch 1; git add 1; git commit -m "1"
touch 2; git add 2; git commit -m "2"
touch 3; git add 3; git commit -m "3"
```

This will produce 3 commits. I want to stay on commit #3 but reset the stage to the state I had on commit #2. I tried to following:

- `git reset --(hard|soft|mixed|merge|keep)`
- `git checkout`
- `git revert`

So after some magic command `blah` I want the following result:

- `git log` shows that the HEAD is still on commit #3
- `ls .` shows  that I have only files `1` and `2` on my filesystem.
- `git diff` or `git diff --cached` shows that file `3` was removed.

I can do `git reset --hard <hash-2>`, but this will move the `HEAD` to commit #2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stay on commit #3"? If you reset to commit 2, then you're not on commit 3 anymore, but working towards commit 4 which undoes what was done in commit 3.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't want to move the HEAD. If I type `git log` I wanna see commit #3 on top.

Comment: That makes little sense to me. Explain your scenario, not your desired end results.

Comment: I explained the scenario above, I want to continue working with changes I had a few commits ago in my stage. I don't wanna produce new commits or move the head. I want to modify those changes and only after that produce a new commit.

Comment: So you want to branch off at commit 2, do some other changes, then replay the changes of commit 3 onto those changes? You actually want to "insert" a commit between 2 and 3? That's what I meant by explaining a scenario, not a result.

Comment: Now I don't wanna create branches at all. Probably I don't even want to history at all, I don't know it yet, I probably will decide this in the future when I start working on my changes. If you use Jetbrains IDE, it has localhistory, you can do reset all files to any stage it had before and this won't affect `.git` repository at all. I want to do the same but with commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git revert HEAD -n
```

With `-n` or `--no-commit` it reverts the changes in the working tree and the index but does not create a commit. `HEAD` can be replaced with other equivalent commit-ish. If you want to commit the reverted, you need to run `git commit`.

If you want to revert some successive commits, taking the case in your comment for example,

```
git revert HEAD~3..HEAD -n
```

Comment: This only reverts single commit. In scenario I have 10 commits, and I want to reset my stage to commit #7 I have to do `git revert #10` `git revert #9` `git revert #8`. Thanks anyway I didn't know about `--no-commit` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to revert the specific files to a given commit. Your HEAD will stay the same.

`git checkout <commit-hash> -- file1/to/restore`

Comment: I saw that answer, but I have no idea what files I had on this commit. Furthermore I had no idea which files were added or removed

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. And to restore all files to that commit's state, just `git checkout <commitHash> -- .`

Comment: This doesn't remove the files I have now. If I do `git checkout hash-commit-2` I would still have files 1-2-3 on my filesystem. I want to fully reset my stage to the commit I had before. The same result I can archive with `git reset --hard` but this command will move the `HEAD`

Comment: What would you do `git checkout hash-commit-2` although nobody suggested it? Did you actually try `git checkout hash-commit-2 -- .`?

Answer (score 1):

One way I can do it in 3 steps:

- `a=$(git rev-parse HEAD)`
- `git reset --hard #hash-commit-2`
- `git reset --soft $a`

Answer (score 1):

You can put any tree-ish (here: that of the previous commit) into the current index like this:

```
git reset @~ -- .
```

which gives you

```
> git status --short
D  3
?? 3
```

Comment: This one is kinda tricky. It doesn't modify the files. It leaves files the same. But stages the changes were made in commits. So `git diff --cached` and `git diff` show opposite changes. E.g. 1) `+a`  and 2) `-a`